# Retornar a posição de uma palavra numa string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Alguém poderia me ajudar com esta questão?

```
def fileRead(file):
        txt = open(file)
        print(txt.read())

def index(filepath, keywords):
    with open(filepath) as f:
        for lineno, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
            matches = [k for k in keywords if k in line]
            if matches:
                result = "{:<15} {}".format(','.join(matches), lineno)
                print(result)

#Programa Principal
fileRead('cores.txt')
fileRead('carta.txt')
index('cores.txt', ["amarelo"])
index('carta.txt', ["azul"])
index('carta.txt', ["verde"])
```

Comment: Qual o problema com o código? se possível [**edite**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/154216/edit) a pergunta e explique qual o objetivo dele, e também poste um trecho de um arquivo e diga o que você espera obter dele!

Comment: @stderr Tenho 2 arquivos .txt que precisam ser lidos e produzam o conjunto das palavras contidas nele .... depois receba como parâmetro o conjunto de palavras de referência e o nome do arquivo de pesquisa, e escreva, na saída padrão, a palavra e seu posicionamento no arquivo de pesquisa caso ela esteja no conjunto de referência. Ex.: Entrada : carta.txt / Saida: ("azul", 3, 5) Mas ... só estou conseguindo imprimir o texto 
(+) 
amarelo         1
azul            3
verde           4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No teu código a palavra e o número da linha já é retornado, para retornar também a posição da palavra na linha, use o [`str.index`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index):

```
pos = line.split().index(keyword)
```

O [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) vai separar a linha em pedaços (separados por espaço) e com `str.index` obter a posição da palavra. Veja um exemplo:

```
s = 'foo bar baz'
i = s.split().index('bar') + 1

print ('bar é a {} palavra de {}'.format(i, s))
# bar é a 2 palavra de foo bar baz
```

No teu código faça assim:

```
def index(filepath, keywords):
    output = "Keyword: {}, Line: {}, Index: {}"

    with open(filepath) as f:
        for lineno, line in enumerate(f, start = 1):
            line = line.rstrip()

            for keyword in keywords:
                if keyword in line:
                    pos = line.split().index(keyword) + 1

                    result = output.format(keyword, lineno, pos)
                    print (result)

index('cores.txt', ['amarelo'])
```

Supondo que o arquivo *cores.txt* tenha o conteúdo abaixo:

> ```
> verde
> vermelho
> amarelo
> cinza amarelo
> azul
> ```

O resultado vai ser:

> ```
> Keyword: amarelo, Line: 3, Index: 1
> Keyword: amarelo, Line: 4, Index: 2
> ```

Comment: @sterr blz! So mais uma duvida...... quanto ao indice esta contando letra a letra... preciso que conte a palavra  
 
Ex.: Keyword: amarelo, Line: 3, Index: 1

Comment: @ABSoares Adicione `+1`. Assim: `line.index(keyword) + 1`. É isso?

Comment: @sterr .......ex> amarelo esta na 2 linha e é a 1 palavra / e na 4 linha , 2  palavra

Comment: @ABSoares Não entendi muito bem. Você quer que escreva "amarelo esta na 2 linha e é a 1 palavra / e na 4 linha , 2 palavra"? O `line.index(keyword) + 1` não funcionou?

Comment: @sterr ... line.index(keyword) + 1 não funcionou

Preciso que me retorne como esta abaixo:

Keyword: amarelo, Line: 4, Index: 2

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45817/discussion-between-absoares-and-stderr).